# Why am I unable to specify a relative path in a .gitignore?

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-for-windows

I have the following directory structure on a windows machine:

```
.gitignore
WebUserApp/
   lib/
      angular/
      angular-ui-router/
      typings/
```

.gitignore and WebUserApp are at the same level and under the WebUserApp is a lib direcotry. The lib directory contains three folders and I want to ignore the sending of the angular and angular-ui-router folders.

I tried the following .gitignore and it did **not work**:

```
# Ignore
WebUserApp/lib/angular
WebUserApp/lib/angular-ui-router
```

I tried this .gitignore and it **worked**:

```
# Ignore
/angular
/angular-ui-router
```

Can someone explain to me why the first version of .gitignore does not work

Comment: Did the `WebUserApp/lib/angular` and `WebUserApp/lib/angular-ui-router` directories exist in git's system BEFORE you added them to the .gitignore? in other words, was their existence registered with git and then you tried to remove them by adding to the .gitignore?

Comment: It did not exist before. In fact the repository on GitHub was new and the .gitignore was created before the push. When I used the first with "WebUserApp/lib/angular" it refused to ignore the angular folder and pushed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
angular/
angular-ui-router/
```

It must be work fine.

Comment: yes this does work fine. But my question is why does the first one not work when I have "WebUserApp/lib" in front ?

Comment: I think you need to add the last slash to reference a folder.

Comment: Umm it's strange, I'm using this same notation in my current project and works perfectly. Maybe it is a problem with Angular libs but I doubt it. Try to ignore any other folder and ignore these folders in other Git project to know exactly where is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
someFolder/
```

ignores all folders named someFolder independent of the level in the tree, as long as it is below the current level.

You actually might want to try:

```
# Ignore
/WebUserApp/lib/angular/
/WebUserApp/lib/angular-ui-router/
```

Then you should be able to reference an relative path.

A slash at the end of the path such as

```
/WebUserApp/lib/angular/
```

git will just ignore folders named like that, but no files or symbolic links.